# how to debug fish script?

Tags: shell, debugging, scripting, fish

You can [debug a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951352/802365) like this:

```
bash -x script [arg1 ...]`
```

#### Question

What is the **`fish` equivalent?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fish use a similar flag system:

```
fish -d 3 script.fish
```

Where [`d` is the debug flag followed by the verbosity level](http://fishshell.com/docs/2.2/commands.html#fish-description):

> -d or --debug-level=DEBUG_LEVEL specify the verbosity level of fish. A higher number means higher verbosity. The default level is 1.

Answer (score 9):

Since https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3427 was merged there is now

```
fish_trace=on script.fish
```

`fish_trace` is just a variable, so you can set it globally or scope it locally inside functions and scripts

```sh
function im-still-debugging
   set -l fish_trace on
   ... etc
end
```

and turn it off with

```sh
set --erase fish_trace
```

as of fish 3.2, fish ignores the actual value you set, it only cares that it is set.