# How to toggle debug mode in Fish shell?

Tags: bash, debugging, fish

In `bash` I do `set -x` and `set +x` enable/disable the debug mode.

I'm aware of [how to debug fish script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34188411/802365), but I would like to toggle debug mode in a more precise way, *e.g.* inside a function.

#### Question

What is the equivalent of `set -x`/`set -x` in Fish shell?

Comment: You can use the [`breakpoint` builtin command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#debugging) from within a function. Is that what you meant?

Comment: sending TRAP signal and all, I've no idea how to do that, this sound overly complicated for basic debugging

Comment: You read the wrong paragraph, you don't need a trap command. Simply use the `breakpoint` command. That halt's the script and drops you into an interactive debugging session. It's not the same as `-x` but it can be used to debug scripts and you can trigger the breakpoint out of your code without need to run the whole script with `-d`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After this question was posed, fish 3.1 added the `fish_trace` variable.

So, instead of `set -x` (which creates an exported variable in fish), `set fish_trace 1` triggers a debug display.

Before fish 3.1, there is no equivalent functionality.